# Wordpress SQL injection

Tags: php, query, mysql

How to make below code safe from sql injection ... I am working in wordpress. 
    global $wpdb;

```
    if($wpdb->insert(
            'votes',
            array(
                    'votes' => $votes,
                    'competition' => $competition,
                    'uid' => $uid


                )
    ) == false) wp_die('Database Insertion failed'); else echo 'Database insertion successful<p />';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The insert method of `$wpdb` already scapes the data taking care of SQL injection. What you should worry about is about data sanitization and validation.

For exmpla:

**Sanitization**

What type of data do you accept in `$votes`? A integer value? If so, be sure `$votes` contains a integer value. You cuold do it, for exmaple, using [`intval` function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php) from PHP. This is sanitization.

```
$votes = intval( $votes );
```

What type of data do you accept in `$competition`? Any string with no HTML, tabs or line breaks, ? If so, be sure `$competition` contains a string value, strip HTML tags and remove tabs and line break; you could do it, for exmaple, using [`sanitize_text_field` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field) from WordPress. This is also sanitization.

```
$competition = sanitize_text_field( $competition );
```

**Data validation**

What value do you accept in `$votes`? From 0 to 100, including both? If so, you could check the value of `$votes`:

```
if( $votes >= 0 && $votes <= 100 ) {

    // Value is correct

} else {

    // Value is not correct. Maybe abort the process?

}
```

Do you have a list of valid competitions? Check the value of `$competition` against it:

```
$valid_competitions = array( 'competition1', 'competition2', 'competition3' );

if( in_array( $competition, $valid_competitions ) ) {

    // Value is correct

} else {

    // Value is not correct. Maybe abort the process?

}
```

Do the same process with `$uid`.

Once you have santize and validate your variables, you are ready to pass them to `$wpdb->insert` method like this (with the third parameter performs a basic sanitization, you can avoid previous sanitization if this is enough for your situation):

```
$wpdb->insert(
     'votes',
     array(
         'votes'       => $votes,
         'competition' => $competition,
         'uid'         => $uid
     ),
     array(
          '%d', // integer data type for $votes
          '%s', // string data type for $competition
          '%d', // integer data type for $uid
     )
);
```

Comment: wow thanks Cybmeta you are the man .... and thanks everyone who read and commented

Comment: `0 <= $votes <= 100` compares a boolean to an integer, rather than doing the expected two integer comparisons. Expect lots of bugs with code like that.

Comment: Do you suggest `if( $votes >= 0 && $votes <= 100 )` is better and/or correct? Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

`wpdb::insert` already protects against SQL injection, it's a wrapper for [`wpdb::prepare`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

For `insert()`, you can pass a third "formats" argument for extra sanitization:

```
$wpdb->insert(
     'votes',
     array(
         'votes' => $votes,
         'competition' => $competition,
         'uid' => $uid
     ),
     array(
          '%s', // $votes will be parsed as a string
          '%s', // $competition will be parsed as a string
          '%d', // $uid will be parsed as an integer
     )
);
```